# Adaptor properties shows driver files instead of names

Tags: networking, windows-11

All of my adapters show raw driver names instead of the proper titles on the
connection properties. See the screenshot as an example, even my wireless adapters do the same thing. A reboot does not fix it either. Not sure when this started, as I haven't been in this panel for a while now.

[image: LAN connection properties]

any ideas what causes this and how to recover it? the adapters work ok and I can still connect to the Internet.

Comment: This appears to be a system environment variable problem, you likely ran software that attempted to update the variable, but due to bad software practices actually introduced a syntax error.

Comment: @Ramhound I think they're ok. they appear as system variables and when I print them in the command window i get echo %windir% => C:\WINDOWS  and echo %systemRoot% => C:\WINDOWS.